# Break very long words with php mpdf

Tags: php, laravel, mpdf

I have generated pdf file, everything works just fine, just one thing, if I write very long word for example:

> qqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqq

All document becomes small and unreadable, for some reason it tries to fit the word in 1 row instead of braking it.
(I have tried word breaks,$mpdf->shrink_tables_to_fit and autosize's) nothing helps.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: which PDF library are you using?

Comment: You might be able to use [automatic hyphentation](https://github.com/mpdf/mpdf-examples/blob/master/example21_hyphenation.php) to solve your problem. Give it a try.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Add css property `overflow:wrap;` to your table or div

Comment: That's exactly what I did and it's working just forgot to post my answer. Thank you anyways and I hope It will help for somone in the future. (I was using phpstorm and for some reason it showed wrap is not available for overflow).

Comment: Works fine. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

> Try this class:

```
.pre-line {
     white-space: pre-line;
 }
```

In html:

```
<p class="pre-line">your-long-text</p>
```